# extract hidden message in a looped video for ctf

Tags: ctf

I have receive a ctf mission which require us to extract something like flag{*******} from the video. As there is no way to attach a video, i have snapped its first 4 frames(which it seems to be looped later in some patterns). It will be great if I can learn some common skills from this challenge to improve my ctf skill in visual challenge.

I want to get the hidden message from this video, or getting its encoding rules.

[frame1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnxSs.png)

[frame2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grd4Z.png)

[frame3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O02ks.png)

[frame4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRL5N.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. To refine you question so that it may be answered here, please take the [tour] and have a look at [ask].